# Flux to List<Objects> without blocking

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, graphql-java

Looking for converting Flux to `List<Object>`. Getting error if I use block(). So, need to conver without blocking calls.

```
Flux.from(Collection.find())
```

Using reactive programming, but graphql expects `List<objects>` and erroring with returning Flux.

Code with Block()

```
public List<Test> findAll() {
        return Flux.from(testCollection.find()).collectList().block();

}
```

**Error :-**

```
block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-kqueue-7
```

Here, I need to return `List<Test>` as I can not send `Flux<Test>` for some reason.

Comment: **You can't.** This needs more detail - there is categorically no way to convert a `Flux` to a `Collection` in a non-blocking fashion. There's ways around the issue - you could switch the flux to use a separate thread where blocking is allowed, you could call your graphql library in a subscriber chain, etc. - but it's difficult / impossible to tell which approach is best with a [mcve].

Comment: If the context is with respect to Spring Webflux, you really don't need because framework subscribes to the flux/mono implicitly.

Comment: Posting tips: (a) please spell-check your work; (b) please always use a capital letter for the personal pronoun "I"; (c) please refrain from adding conversational material such as greetings and thanks; (d) always use the preview pane, so you can see if your material has been rendered correctly. The generics expressions needed repair here.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, **You can't**. The reactive pattern is to stay in a flow.

So,

```
Mono<GraphqlResponse> = Flux.just("A", "B" "C")
  .collectList()
  .map(this::someMethod);

GraphqlResponse someMethod(List<String> abcs) {
    return graphQl.doSomething(abcs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

following example is converting `flux<Object>` to `List<Object>` but remember that converting a Flux to a List makes the whole thing NOT reactive:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flux<String> flux = Flux.just("test1", "test2", "test3");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    flux.collectList().subscribe(list::addAll);
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `Collection` class is from some reactor library doing some tcp/http call? `collection.find` returns a `Flux/Mono/Publisher` I assume? Then thats not because of `collectList` doesn't allow you to do that, thats because you are trying to run `block` on a thread which is a `NonBlocking` thread, I assume `collection.find` publish the elements on a thread which is an instance of `NonBlocking`, from its name `reactor-http-kqueue-7` which is probably a netty thread.

You can take a look at `BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet` method which tells you why

```
    final T blockingGet() {
        if (Schedulers.isInNonBlockingThread()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
...
```

If you have to get the result from the caller thread (which calls Flux.from), then you can do

```
Flux.from(testCondition.find())
.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
.collectList()
.block()
```